# Entity framework LINQ with value OR null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following EF linq query to get all the employess or specific employee, in case if empId has value.

But the EF is not generating the expected query and it ignores `OR` condition always

```
from employee 
where employee.DepartmentId == depId && ((employee.Id == empId) || (employee.Id == null))
.ToList()
```

Expected Query

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentId = @DepId AND (Id=@empId OR Id IS NULL)
```

Generated Query by EF when value is passed

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentId = @DepId AND (Id=@empId)
```

Generated Query by EF when value is null

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentId = @DepId AND (Id IS NULL)
```

> Note: No Employee record has Id value NULL and it returns 0 instead of
>   all employees

How to write linq for this `Id=@empId OR Id IS NULL` ?

Comment: Your expected query returns only matching ID's or those ID's which are `NULL`(which is impossible according to what you say in your `Note`). So what you actually want? I guess you want to bypass the check when the value is `null` but that is something else than what your sql query does.

Comment: It seems odd to me that your `Employee` table would have any rows where `Id` is `null`. Isn't this the primary key for that table? If not, you may want to consider renaming it.

Comment: Id is an Id so it cannot be null and I'm quite sure you model has it not nullable `public int Id {get; set; }`, that's why EF generate that query

Comment: @DavidG no values with null. I usually write SQL to filter specific data or all data using `(Column=@value OR Column IS NULL)`. I tried with EF for same and didnt work for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say this is your expected query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentId = @DepId AND (Id=@empId OR Id IS NULL)
```

but i'm pretty sure that it is not, because the `Id` is never null (what you also say in your *Note*) because it is the primary key of that table. You actually mean this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentId = @DepId AND (Id=@empId OR @empId IS NULL)
```

so you want to bypass the check and return all records if the parameter is `NULL`. Note that this is not the best way performance wise. You should use a query without filter when you don't want to filter by `Id`. I'm afraid this will not produce the most efficient query plan. I'd use this:

```
IQueryable<Employee> allDepartmentEmployees = 
    from employee in ...
    where employee.DepartmentId == depId;
    select employee;

if(empId.HasValue) // presuming it's a nullable type
{
    allDepartmentEmployees = allDepartmentEmployees.Where(e => e.Id == empId.Value);     
}

List<Employee> employeeList = allDepartmentEmployees.ToList();
```

So only filter if the parameter is given. Then this will only return one record.

Comment: Thanks and It looks nice and I am trying now. Actually I have simplified my question by asking with an example with one table. In Actual, I join many table and in where condition I need to apply this additional filter. Let me try your code and see how the EF applies where condition

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ to SQL translation simplified your query logic. They are functionally equivalent.

You should not try to write LINQ in a way that it generates a specific SQL you expect. You are writing LINQ to do a specific operation. If the resulting query does not match your expectation, try to understand why.

When your comparison is `(Id=@empId OR Id IS NULL)`

- If `@empId` is always NULL, then `(Id IS NULL)` is a functionally equivalent simplification
- If `@empId` is a value or may be null then `(Id=@empId)` is a functionally equivalent simplification

You did not say which DB / DB driver you use with Entity Framework, but you can verify that comparing against NULL is always false:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

MS SQL Server returns `0` for this query. So NULL is not equal to NULL.

Database Engines typically interpret and handle NULL a bit differently than C# does null. NULL is *unknown* rather than *unset*. In MS SQL Server `IS NULL` is used to compare against NULL rather than `=`, `!=` or `<>`.

For MS SQL Server see [NULL and UNKNOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)